# Algorithm to solve constraint satisfaction problems

Tags: constraint-satisfaction, constraint-programming

I have group of people. Each person can be described by few characteristics:

```
age, occupation, city, favorite_color
```

I would like to generate 60 random people and combine them into pairs.
With a constrain that no person in a pair can share any characteristic, for example I can't have two people in a pair whose **favorite_color** is green.

I was thinking about using Backtracking algorithm to solve it.

What other algorithms I could use to solve this particular problem?
I would like to research and implement some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an algorithm to find a [perfect matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_general_graphs) in a graph.  Build a graph where each vertex represents a person, and draw an edge between each two people who don't share any characteristic, then look for a perfect matching.  If none exists, you can throw away that data and generate a new random sample, and repeat until you find a valid solution.